# React search bar on homepage to redirect to results page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, searchbar

I am trying to create a search bar on a website's homepage to redirect to the search page and display the results, but the users can continue their search from there. So a functionality similar to that of google, where when we first enter there is only a search bar, and once we search, we can continue searching from the page displaying the results. This is my current code and I do not know how to implement this functionality.

```
import React from "react";
import "./home.css";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import SearchField from 'react-search-field';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import axios from 'axios';


export default class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        searchResults: [],
        search: '',
        
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSearchClick= this.onSearchClick.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class = "row body flex-nowrap">
                    <div class="bg-image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-text">
                        <div class="title" >
                        Oerinspanish <br/>
                        </div>
                        Recursos educativos de acceso libre <br/>
                        para la enseñanza del español <br/> <br/> <br/>
                        
                        <SearchField class="search" placeholder= 'búsqueda' input type= "text" required value={this.state.input} 
                            onSearchClick={this.onSearchClick}>
                            <Redirect to={{
                                pathname: '/search',
                                state: { searchResults: this.state.searchResults }
                            }}/>
                        </SearchField>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    onSearchClick(event) {
        let url = 'http://localhost:3000/search' + encodeURI(this.state.search) + '&json=1';
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            let data = {
            searchResults: response.data,
            };
            this.setState(data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you rendering a `Redirect` as a child of `SearchField`? When the `Redirect` is rendered it will redirect immediately. When do you want to redirect/navigate?

Comment: I want to redirect when the user clicks on the search icon

Comment: Is the search icon a/the child element/component of `SearchField`? You'll need to issue an imperative navigation (i.e. like `history.push`) versus a declarative navigation (i.e. a `Redirect` component), likely in the `onSearchClick` handler.

Comment: would you be able to check the new code? I have made some new changes. I am new to react and could not find any sources on imperative navigation

Comment: actually my main problem is that in my website when I search a specific thing on the search page, the link to the page remains the same, so when I fetch it, I cannot adjust it to understand the word I am entering to the bar. That is why I need to connect the two search bars (the one on the home page and search page)rather than use a url.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation should be done in response to the GET request in `onSearchClick` successfully resolving, not in the middle of the select input. The imperative (vs declarative) bit is about *explicitly* issuing the command, i.e. invoking a function to do a *thing*, versus deferring that to other code.

Suggestion:

Don't bother with the local component `searchResults` state. Once the GET request has resolved and you've the search results in the response, issue a redirect via the `history` object to the target route with the results stored in route state.

```
onSearchClick(event) {
  const { search } = this.state;
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/search' + encodeURI(search) + '&json=1';
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      this.history.replace({
        pathname: "/search",
        state: {
          searchResults: response.data,
        },
      });
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}

...

<SearchField
  class="search"
  placeholder="búsqueda"
  input
  type="text"
  required
  value={this.state.input} 
  onSearchClick={this.onSearchClick}
/>
```

This requires the class component to receive the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) so it can access `this.history`. To do this then this component either needs to be directly rendered by a `Route` component or wrapped in the [withRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC to have them injected and available.